# installing hhvm on centOS 7.2 With Apache 2.4

Tags: php, centos7, hhvm

I've been looking into this and I have some questions about it.
As far as I understand, hhvm is a framework developed by facebook to support the "hack" and "php" languages. If I install this in place of php, my php scripts will run faster, more efficiently and use less server side resources, and I wont have to change any of the code or do anything. True / False?

my second problem, is i cant get the hhvm to install. Don't know why.
The closest guide to follow i could find was here:
https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/building-and-installing-hhvm-on-centos-7.x

I have root access to the shell.
`yum update -y` <------- says everything is up to date
`yum install -y epel-release` <---------- latest version installed nothing to do

typing this

```
yum install cpp gcc-c++ cmake3 git psmisc {binutils,boost,jemalloc,numactl}-devel \
{ImageMagick,sqlite,tbb,bzip2,openldap,readline,elfutils-libelf,gmp,lz4,pcre}-devel \
lib{xslt,event,yaml,vpx,png,zip,icu,mcrypt,memcached,cap,dwarf}-devel \
{unixODBC,expat,mariadb}-devel lib{edit,curl,xml2,xslt}-devel \
glog-devel oniguruma-devel ocaml gperf enca libjpeg-turbo-devel openssl-devel \
mariadb mariadb-server {fastlz,double-conversion,re2}-devel make -y
```

gives

```
yum install cpp gcc-c++ cmake3 git psmisc {binutils,boost,jemalloc,numactl}-

devel {ImageMagick,sqlite,tbb,bzip2,openldap,readline,elfutils-libelf,gmp,lz4,pcre}-devel lib{xslt,event,yaml,vpx,png,zip,icu,mcrypt,memcached,cap,dwarf}-devel {unixODBC,expat,mariadb}-devel lib{edit,curl,xml2,xslt}-devel glog-devel oniguruma-devel ocaml gperf enca libjpeg-turbo-devel openssl-devel mariadb mariadb-server {fastlz,double-conversion,re2}-devel make -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, tsflags, universal-hooks
http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/jkaluza/httpd24/epel-7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please create a bug on https://bugs.centos.org/

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 208.100.0.204
 * base: ca.mirror.babylon.network
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: muug.ca
 * remi-safe: repo1.dal.innoscale.net
 * updates: muug.ca
Package cpp-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-c++-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package cmake3-3.6.1-2.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package git-1.8.3.1-6.el7_2.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package psmisc-22.20-9.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package binutils-devel-2.23.52.0.1-55.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package jemalloc-devel-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package sqlite-devel-3.7.17-8.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package tbb-devel-4.1-9.20130314.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package bzip2-devel-1.0.6-13.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package openldap-devel-2.4.40-9.el7_2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package readline-devel-6.2-9.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package elfutils-libelf-devel-0.163-3.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package lz4-devel-r131-1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package pcre-devel-8.32-15.el7_2.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libxslt-devel-1.1.28-5.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libevent-devel-2.0.21-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libyaml-devel-0.1.4-11.el7_0.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libvpx-devel-1.3.0-5.el7_0.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 2:libpng-devel-1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libzip-devel-0.10.1-8.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libmcrypt-devel-2.5.8-13.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libmemcached-devel-1.0.16-5.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libcap-devel-2.22-8.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libdwarf-devel-20130207-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package unixODBC-devel-2.3.1-11.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package expat-devel-2.1.0-8.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libedit-devel-3.0-12.20121213cvs.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libcurl-devel-7.29.0-25.el7.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libxml2-devel-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libxslt-devel-1.1.28-5.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glog-devel-0.3.3-8.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package oniguruma-devel-5.9.5-3.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package ocaml-4.01.0-22.7.el7_2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gperf-3.0.4-8.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libjpeg-turbo-devel-1.2.90-5.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:openssl-devel-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:make-3.82-21.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ImageMagick-devel.x86_64 0:6.8.6.3-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ImageMagick-libs = 6.8.6.3-4.el6 for package: ImageMagick-devel-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: ImageMagick = 6.8.6.3-4.el6 for package: ImageMagick-devel-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.1()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-devel-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.1()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-devel-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
---> Package boost-devel.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: boost = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_wserialization.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_wave.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_timer.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_system.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_signals.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_serialization.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_regex.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_random.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_python.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_math_tr1l.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_math_tr1f.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_math_tr1.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_math_c99l.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_math_c99f.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_math_c99.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_log_setup.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_log.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_locale.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_graph.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_date_time.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_context.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_chrono.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_atomic.so.1.54.0()(64bit) for package: boost-devel-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
---> Package double-conversion-devel.x86_64 0:2.0.1-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: double-conversion(x86-64) = 2.0.1-3.el7 for package: double-conversion-devel-2.0.1-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdouble-conversion.so.1()(64bit) for package: double-conversion-devel-2.0.1-3.el7.x86_64
---> Package enca.x86_64 0:1.18-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package fastlz-devel.x86_64 0:0.1.0-0.1.20070619svnrev12.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: fastlz(x86-64) = 0.1.0-0.1.20070619svnrev12.el7 for package: fastlz-devel-0.1.0-0.1.20070619svnrev12.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfastlz.so.0()(64bit) for package: fastlz-devel-0.1.0-0.1.20070619svnrev12.el7.x86_64
---> Package gmp-devel.x86_64 1:6.0.0-12.el7_1 will be installed
---> Package libicu-devel.x86_64 0:50.1.2-15.el7 will be installed
---> Package mariadb.x86_64 1:5.5.50-1.el7_2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.50-1.el7_2 for package: 1:mariadb-5.5.50-1.el7_2.x86_64
---> Package mariadb-devel.x86_64 1:5.5.50-1.el7_2 will be installed
---> Package mariadb-server.x86_64 1:5.5.50-1.el7_2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBD-MySQL for package: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.50-1.el7_2.x86_64
---> Package numactl-devel.x86_64 0:2.0.9-6.el7_2 will be installed
---> Package re2-devel.x86_64 0:20160401-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: re2(x86-64) = 20160401-2.el7 for package: re2-devel-20160401-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libre2.so.0()(64bit) for package: re2-devel-20160401-2.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ImageMagick.x86_64 0:6.8.6.3-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package ImageMagick-libs.x86_64 0:6.8.6.3-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpng12.so.0(PNG12_0)(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtiff.so.3()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng12.so.0()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgs.so.8()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libIlmImf.so.6()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
---> Package boost.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: boost-thread = 1.54.0-7.el6 for package: boost-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
---> Package boost-atomic.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-chrono.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-context.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-date-time.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-filesystem.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-graph.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-graph-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-graph-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-graph-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
---> Package boost-iostreams.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-locale.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-locale-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-locale-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-locale-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
---> Package boost-log.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-math.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-python.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-random.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-regex.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-regex-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-regex-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-regex-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
---> Package boost-serialization.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-signals.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-system.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-test.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-timer.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package boost-wave.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package double-conversion.x86_64 0:2.0.1-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package fastlz.x86_64 0:0.1.0-0.1.20070619svnrev12.el7 will be installed
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.50-1.el7_2 will be installed
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:4.023-5.el7 will be installed
---> Package re2.x86_64 0:20160401-2.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ImageMagick-libs.x86_64 0:6.8.6.3-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgs.so.8()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libIlmImf.so.6()(64bit) for package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
---> Package boost-graph.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-graph-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-graph-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-graph-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
---> Package boost-locale.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-locale-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-locale-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-locale-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
---> Package boost-regex.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-regex-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-regex-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) for package: boost-regex-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64
---> Package boost-thread.x86_64 0:1.54.0-7.el6 will be installed
---> Package compat-libtiff3.x86_64 0:3.9.4-11.el7 will be installed
---> Package libpng12.x86_64 0:1.2.50-7.el7_2 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: ImageMagick-last-6.9.6.2-1.el7.remi.x86_64 conflicts ImageMagick < 6.9.6.2
--> Processing Conflict: ImageMagick-last-devel-6.9.6.2-1.el7.remi.x86_64 conflicts ImageMagick-devel < 6.9.6.2
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: boost-locale-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: boost-graph-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
           Requires: libgs.so.8()(64bit)
Error: Package: boost-locale-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: boost-regex-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-libs-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
           Requires: libIlmImf.so.6()(64bit)
Error: ImageMagick-last conflicts with ImageMagick-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
Error: ImageMagick-last-devel conflicts with ImageMagick-devel-6.8.6.3-4.el6.x86_64
Error: Package: boost-graph-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: boost-graph-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
           Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: boost-regex-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
           Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: boost-regex-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: boost-locale-1.54.0-7.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
           Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

note (--skip-broken) parameter doesnt do much

`yum install {fribidi,libc-client,glib2}-devel -y` <------ up to date nothing to do

There are also more errors on the following steps trying to install from github.

Is anyone able to assist me with what im doing wrong? and should I be installing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: About performance, PHP 7 comes with huge improvements (usually ~50% time and ~50% memory saved), and various bench (on real applications, e.g. drupal, wordpress, ...) results show it is now very close to HHVM (sometime a bit better, sometime a bit lesser)

Answer (score 0):

HHVM is intended to be able to be a replacement for the default php runtime. You can get more general information about it on its [website](http://hhvm.com/%20website). Although there are some known [minor incompatibilities](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20label%3A%22php5%20incompatibility%22), so you may want to look through the issues before you switch over.

I have not built hhvm on centos so I can't help you there. Also there are no official binaries for centos. There are some unofficial builds you can use. Here is one that I've used on [fedora](https://www.ulyaoth.net/resources/hhvm.21/) that can be installed on centos7.